# Managing routes in reactjs app in production

Tags: reactjs, react-fullstack

How is routing handled in a built react app?

Specifically, in a development environment, we can simply hit `<host>:<port>/<some-path>` and the corresponding component is loaded, but once the app is **built**, we get a bunch of static files and single **index.html** file, which are then served by some server.
Now, upon hitting the url `<server-host>:<server-port>`, the app works as intended, but upon entering the path, say `<server-host>:<server-port>/<component-path>`, a **404 error** is returned. 
If there is, say a button, upon clicking which, the same `/<component-path>` is to be redirected, the app works, but then again upon refreshing that page, **404 error** occurs.

How can this be solved? What is the correct way to serve such apps having many components at different routes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***approach1:(recommended)***

In `server config` you should `point` all ***urls*** ( `http://ipaddress:port/<* any url pattern>`) to `index.html` of react-app .   this is known as `fallback-mechanism`.

And  when any request comes,`index.html`  of React app will take care of that automatically because it is single page application.

***approach2:***

Use **HashRouter** in React app. So You will not have to configure anything.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on which server you are deploying to, you should redirect all errors to the index.html look for the configuration maybe htaccess or for example if it an AWS S3 bucket you just specify the error page to the same index.html file that is served. Then you handle actual error in your code using a routing library like maybe react-router-dom to take care of actual error. Your failure is because in normal circumstances in a static host when you provide a URL like `<server-port>/<component-path>` the assumption the server makes is that there is a folder with name `component-path` in your root directory which has an index file from where to load and display but in the case of React single page application, everything is managed by the index.html. So every request has to pass via the index.html